# Xcode referencing old copies of files

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, file-management

Changes I've been making to code in certain files are being ignored by Xcode. I've traced it to the fact that Xcode is keeping its own older version of the code files somehow... these older/duplicate files are not shown anywhere in the Finder window for the project's folder and persist after cleaning the project with both "Clean" and "Clean Build Folder", closing out of Xcode, and restarting the computer.

**Let me try and explain:**

I have a file called QuestionPicker.h and a corresponding QuestionPicker.m

When I make a change to the code in either of those, Xcode is oblivious that any changes have been made and continues to use the old version of the code in those files.

When I "Alt-click" to see the declaration:

[image]

and then click on the QuestionPicker.h shown, it takes me to a "nonexistent" old version of the file from before I made my changes to it. When I look in the header bar, this file is not shown as being a part of my project, but more like an isolated file:

[image]

If I click on the real QuestionPicker.h from the Project Navigator, it shows my most recent changes to the code, and the header bar shows the file as part of my project's overall codebase:

[image]

One thing I can interestingly do is select and copy ALL of the code in my QuestionPicker.h file with changes, open the old-copy-somehow-persisting-version from the "Alt-click" declaration, and paste the code there. This doesn't fix the underlying issue, just adds my changes to the wrong old version of a file that Xcode is using when it shouldn't be. I might be able to continue coding with this hack IF I was able to do the same in the .m implementation file, except I have no way of getting into the old-copy-somehow-persisting-version of the .m file since it doesn't exist anywhere in the Project Navigator, the Finder window for the project, or anywhere else that I can access.

Any ideas? Any help? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Xcode does not keep the source files, it just points to them. Most likely you are editing a copy Xcode is not using.

In Xcode check the location of the file it is using:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply! The File Inspector (as in your screenshot) shows the location as "Relative to Group" and shows the full path of the file as expected when I select the file I am editing from the Project Navigator. But this is still not the file that Xcode is running the code from or checking for errors upon building. For example, properties that I've added to the file I'm editing are not available from the autocompletion menu (pressing Esc when typing) but properties from an older version of the file that no longer exists in my project or Finder still show in the autocompletion menu...

Comment: I updated the image, check that the box is checked under Target Membership. There is a possibility of an alias of link pointing to another file. Also Right Click on the file name in the left column and select "Show in Finder" to verify the actual file.

Comment: Should've mentioned it earlier, but yes the Target Membership is checked.

Comment: As a last resort, delete file file from the left column and re-add it by dragging the correct file back to Xcode.

Comment: What version of Xcodce are you running? Is there another Xcode project that is an old copy?

Comment: So I kept my hopes up as I deleted the files and dragged them back in. Same problems. Then I deleted the files again and without dragging them back in, tried the autocompletion for code and Xcode STILL knew what properties of the file were available even though the file was deleted from the project. A few more attempts to drag in/delete and the project actually built successfully and ran the code I wanted!!! Tested making a new change and I see that I'll still have the same issue going forward... but I can now continue my work assuming that this particular file is the finished code as is.

Comment: Running Xcode 6.3.2 (can't wait for Xcode 7 to GM out of beta! Especially excited for UIStackViews to help with Auto Layout!)

Comment: Perform a Finder search of your top directory for files containing some rather unique code. Get it down to only one file. If you are concerned about deleteing a file, make .zip archive (Right-Click Compress) of it prior to deleting.

Comment: With a Finder search as you suggested for one of the lines of code I changed specifically for this project, I have found the file that Xcode is referencing!!! It is a file with the same name but in a different folder for an older project. What is tying Xcode back to this file??? It is acting like an "absolute path" link to the file in a different folder instead of using the file marked "relative to group" in the project. I should post a new question as THIS is the real issue... not sure if I should mark your answer as correct but you helped me understand the real problem I should ask about.

Comment: File a bug with Apple http://bugreport.apple.com. You might consider the comments part of the answer.

Comment: I deleted the files that were in the other folder/other project that Xcode was still linked to for whatever reason. Once those were gone, and I confirmed that Xcode no longer was aware in code of files that shouldn't have been connected to the project, I was able to add the correct files back to the project and the link to these new ones finally became the established link in Xcode. Once everything was working with this project's files, I tried returning the old project's files to their place and the link was again taken from right to old. Maddening but at least I can manage it now... thanks!